# How to setup default browser installed as flatpak

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

Since I uninstalled Firefox from official Debian repositories and installed it as flatpak, I have no default browser set anymore. If I go to Settings->Default Applications, I get this prompt: "Choose a custom Web browser". Not sure how to enter path to a flatpak Firefox there.

Comment: OK, I will ask there. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614899/setting-a-flatpak-app-as-the-default-web-browser